# Python data fields initialisation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Seems like an obvious question, but I can't find the answer.

In Python, how do I initialise *class data* (not *instance attributes*).

```
class MyClass:
    DATA = MyClass()
```

Doesn't work, because `MyClass()` isn't defined yet.

```
class MyClass:
    pass

MyClass.DATA = MyClass()
```

Is confusing to the human reader, linter, IDE and autocomplete.

Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You should typehint it and define it afterwards:

```
class MyClass:
    DATA: ClassVar['MyClass'] # Will get set afterwards
MyClass.DATA = MyClass()
```

This should solve the problem for autocomplete(IDE) and human reader. Should also be ok for most linter.